# How to sort the output to exclude a regex pattern?

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, sorting, groovy, filtering

I have the following Groovy code which queries AWS to receive a list of CIDR blocks in use and populate an array with it:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy
def regions = ['us-west-2', 'us-east-1', 'eu-west-1']
        def output = []
        regions.each { region ->
            def p = ['/usr/bin/aws', 'ec2', 'describe-vpcs', '--region', region].execute() | 'grep -w CidrBlock'.execute() | ['awk', '{print $2}'].execute() | ['tr', '-d', '"\\"\\|,\\|\\{\\|\\\\["'].execute() | 'uniq'.execute()
            p.waitFor()
            p.text.eachLine { line ->
                output << line
            }
        }
        output = output.sort { a, b ->
        def aparts = a.split('[./]').collect { it as short }
        def bparts = b.split('[./]').collect { it as short }
        (0..4).collect { aparts[it] <=> bparts[it] }.find() ?: 0
        }
        output.each {
            println it
        }
```

In some regions the CIDR blocks are 172.31.0.0/16 and in others 10.100.0.0/16.

I want the output of the script to include only 10.100.* CIDR blocks and I don't want the 172.* networks to even appear in the output.

Current output looks like so:

```
itai@Itais-MacBook-Pro ~ -  $ groovy populate_jenkins_parameters_cidr_blocks.groovy
172.30.0.0/16
172.31.0.0/16
10.100.0.0/16
10.105.0.0/16
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the output collection, you can apply filter using `find` or `findAll` as shown below.

```
def outputCollection = ['172.30.0.0/16', '172.31.0.0/16', '10.100.0.0/16', '10.100.0.1/16','10.105.0.0/16'] 
println outputCollection.findAll{ it =~ /10.100.*/ }.sort()
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/ZOt8XW)</kbd>

EDIT: Based on the comment.
Remove last 8 statements in your code and just add just below statements.

```
output.findAll{ it =~ /10.100.*/ }.sort()
println output
```

Comment: What does it show when you do `println output` in your script? Hope you got what has to be done based on the above sample? i.e., find and apply `regex`

Comment: @ItaiGanot, May I suggest you to see the demo and see if it is yielding the desired output for you first?

Comment: I've edit the output line to this: output = output.findAll{ it =~ /10.100.*/ }.sort , for now it seems like it works ok, but it's not a good indication as at the moment there's only one CIDR up, I'll update soon when another is up, thanks

Comment: You are confusing by saying `it works ok, but it is not good indication`. Appreciate upvotes for the helpful answers and accept it as answered if that solves the issue.

Comment: @ItaiGanot, but the difference can be seen in the demo sample right as it has the other IPs in its collection. And does the filtering.

Comment: True, but in my case I print an array and not a list... it would have been best if you could show me how to edit my code to reflect the change I want if you please.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to eliminate the unwanted blocks as early as possible.

You can do it as early as they are collected. So change:

```
p.text.eachLine { line ->
  output << line
}
```

to

```
p.text.eachLine { line ->
  if (!(line =~ /^172\./)) output << line
}
```